# how to remove sentences with conjuctions in R

Tags: r, regex

I have text, an example of which is as follows

***Input***

```
c(",At the end of the study everything was great\n,There is an funny looking thing somewhere but I didn't look at it too hard\nSome other sentence\n The test ended.",",Not sure how to get this regex sorted\nI don't know how to get rid of sentences between the two nearest carriage returns but without my head spinning\nHow do I do this")
```

***The expected output is***

```
,At the end of the study everything was great\n,Some other sentence\nThe test ended.
,Not sure how to get this regex sorted\n\nHow do I do this
```

***I tried:***

```
  x[, y] <- gsub(".*[Bb]ut .*?(\\.|\n|:)", "", x[, y])
```

but it eradicated the whole sentence. How do I remove the phrase with 'but' in it and keep the rest of the phrases in each sentence?

Comment: Maybe something like `gsub(pattern = "(\n)(.*but.*)(\n)", replacement = " \\1, \\3", text)`, the `\\1` and `\\3`are capturing group operators if you want to keep the `\n`

Comment: I've changed the example as there are usually more than three phrases which means the regex captures too much. Do I need a non-greedy positive lookbehind here?

Comment: Instead of `/n`, did you mean to use `\n` (LF)?

Comment: Oops. Typo corrected

Comment: See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/ul5myc), [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZlJYzm/1).

Comment: OK and what if the input is this: c(",At the end of the study everything was great\nSome other sentence\n,There is an funny looking thing somewhere but I didn't look at it too hard\n The test ended."

Comment: Also, I wonder if the only problem is due to the fact that in a TRE regex a `.` matches any char including a line break and if you just add `(?n)` at the start of the pattern it might fix that (`gsub("(?n).*[Bb]ut .*?(\\.|\n|:)", "", x[, y])`). Of course word boundaries are preferable, but please check your requirements. Are you really trying to match up to the first `:`, newline or `.` after `but`?

Comment: OK, I see it is working, see my answer with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
x <- c(",At the end of the study everything was great\n,There is an funny looking thing somewhere but I didn't look at it too hard\nSome other sentence\n The test ended.", ",Not sure how to get this regex sorted\nI don't know how to get rid of sentences between the two nearest carriage returns but without my head spinning\nHow do I do this")
gsub(".*\\bbut\\b.*[\r\n]*", "", x, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
gsub("(?n).*\\bbut\\b.*[\r\n]*", "", x, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/RWzm61)

The PCRE pattern matches:

- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, 0 or more, as many as possible
- `\\bbut\\b` - a whole word `but` (`\b` are word boundaries)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, 0 or more, as many as possible
- `[\r\n]*` - 0 or more line break chars.

Note that the first `gsub` has a `perl=TRUE` argument that makes R use the PCRE regex engine to parse the pattern, and `.` does not match a line break char there. The second `gsub` uses a TRE (default) regex engine, and one needs to use `(?n)` inline modifier to make `.` fail to match line break chars there.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you mixed up "\n" and "/n", which I did correct.

My idea for a solution:

1) Simply catch all chars which are no linebreak ([^\n]) before and after the "but".

2) **(Edit)** To address the issue Wiktors found, we also have to check that no char ([^a-zA-Z]) is directly before or after the "but".

```
x <- c(",At the end of the study everything was great\n,There is an funny looking thing somewhere but I didn't look at it too hard\nSome other sentence\n The test ended.",
       ",Not sure how to get this regex sorted\nI don't know how to get rid of sentences between the two nearest carriage returns but without my head spinning\nHow do I do this")

> gsub("[^\n]*[^a-zA-Z]but[^a-zA-Z][^\n]*", "", x)
[1] ",At the end of the study everything was great\n\nSome other sentence\n The test ended."
[2] ",Not sure how to get this regex sorted\n\nHow do I do this"
```

Comment: This will remove lines with words like `button`.

Comment: A `"[^\n]*[^a-zA-Z]but[^a-zA-Z][^\n]*"` is not the best work around for word boundaries, and though technically it is incorrect (since `[^A-Za-z]` matches a line break char), it might work for OP. Besides, you do not need a workaround for `.`, `(?n)` modifier in a TRE regex makes `.` fail to match newlines.

Comment: Both answers work but to be honest I like Wiktors more as I think its more versatile. I'm not sure I understand why (\n)(.*but.*) doesnt capture everything from the first \n to the but though...however it works